# How to call function from SmartContract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, web3.py

I have a smart contract deployed having the following function.

```
function getTime() public view returns (uint){
       return now;
   }
```

However, when I try to call the function like this. ("einstance" being the instance of the contract):

```
tme=einstance.functions.getTime()
tme
```

I receive:

```
<Function getTime() bound to ()>
```

How can I retrieve the time from this?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Web3 v1.2.6

const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

const contractJSON = require('/path/to/build/contracts/Contract.json');
const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(contractJSON.abi, 'CONTRACT_DEPLOYED_ADDRESS');

async function getTimeFromContract() {
  const time = await contractInstance.methods.getTime().call();
  console.log(`Time returned from the contract: ${time}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `tme=einstance.call().getTime()`.

Comment: I get the following error!:
MismatchedABI: ("The function 'call' was not found in this contract's abi. ", 'Are you sure you provided the correct contract abi?')

Comment: Sorry, the `functions` part is redundant. I mistakenly copied it from your question (where did you come up with that from anyway?).

Comment: Because when I write this:
tme=einstance.getTime().call()
I get the following error: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'getTime'

Comment: @DebaSen: How are you initializing the `einstance` object?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have deployed your contract. If it was deployed correctly then you can call.

```
einstance.functions.getTime().call()
```

where einstance must be instance of web3._utils.datatypes.Contract.

Little brief on how to install your contract

Step1:
Compile your contract and get the bytecode and abi. You can install a specific version of sold compiler on your machine .

```
For abi
solc --abi test.sol

for bytecode
solc --bin test.sol
```

The instantiate by copying your abi and bytecode

```
Test = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
```

Then you have to deploy your contract, I did it on localchain

```
w3 = Web3("http://localhost:8545")
w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]  
tx_hash = Test.constructor().transact()
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
```

Your deployed contract

```
deployed = w3.eth.contract(
            address=tx_receipt.contractAddress,
            abi=abi
```

Now you can call the functions on your deployed contract by

```
deployed.functions.getTime().call()
>>>1585998887
```

I used this contract

```
pragma solidity 0.6.4;

contract Test {

    function getTime() public view returns (uint){
       return now;
   }

}
```

Make sure your solc compiler (Installed on your machine) is same as in pragma statement.